# How to do infinite scrolling in Flutter DataTable?

Tags: flutter, datatable, scroll, infinite

I am developing a flutter web.
How to do infinite scrolling in Flutter DataTable?
Sliver + datatable

Comment: Is there any results on this research?

Answer (score -1):

Use scrollDirection: Axis.vertical inside SingleChildScrollView.